# how to use eval() in python mako templating

Tags: python, eval, mako

In python it is possible to dynamically create variables names using `eval('dyn_var_name')`.
I want to do this in my mako template but the example code below:

```
from mako.template import Template
print Template("hello ${eval('data{}'.format(0))}!").render(data0="world")
```

returns with a `NameError: name 'data0' is not defined`, ie. the variable name is still a string `'data0'` and doesnt correspond to the appropriate keyname `data0`; `eval()` hasnt done its job. How to go about accomplishing this?

thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this using the `pageargs` dictionary rather than `eval`:

```
from mako.template import Template
print Template("hello ${pageargs['data{}'.format(0)]}!").render(data0="world")
```

However, from your example it sounds like you might have a bunch of variables each named like `data0`, `data1`, `data2`, etc. Why not pass them to render as a list rather than as many similarly named variables? Something like:

```
`Template("hello ${data[0]}!").render(data=["world"])`)
```

Also see [keep data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html).

Comment: yes i do have data0, data1, data2, etc. While I agree that would be a better way to do it, it would require a rewrite of a larger piece of code i'd rather not touch unless necessary. Your solution works just fine, thx!